# The condition that wind would effect indicated airspeed

Tags: cruise

What is the one condition that wind does effects our indicated airspeed?

Comment: Can you be more specific? There is no one such condition, but rather many.

Comment: If your question is "does wind variations affect indicated airspeed in flight?" then yes, but only momentarily due to the aircraft inertia. The aircraft tends to remain at the same groundspeed while its speed relative to the wind has changed. However it quickly gains or loses groundspeed to mach the same previous IAS as engines can create only a move which is relative to the ambient air speed (via propeller or jet).

Answer (score 3):

There are many, but most obvious is when the aircraft is on the ground.